# How to stop/disable PyUnit when using PyDev

Tags: eclipse, pydev, python-unittest

I would like to have PyUnit stop showing up each time I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>. It's distracting and I don't understand it's output anyways, nor did I (knowingly) elect to enable it. I can't find anything in PyDev settings.

[image]

Comment: In case it matters, I run `Helios Service Release 1` whose Build id is **20100917-0705**.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl + F11 has actually nothing to do with PyUnit. It is a key binding that per default runs the script you last launched. In your case the last launch you made must have been a PyUnit launch. If you would have launched the script with *Run As* then this would be launched if you press Ctrl + F11.

This could be a possible solution to your problem:

Remove the PyUnit launcher from Run History (*Run -> Run Configurations* and then delete the the configurations listed below *Python unittest*.

Hope that helped!

Cherio Woltan

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in the PyDev > PyUnit settings (in the same screen you've shown), if you uncheck the 'show the results in the unittest results view', it should do what you want (i.e.: stop showing the PyUnit view)... or that's not what you wanted?